# Reverse the string using for loop in python IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to reverse the string using following code !

```
def rev_string(text):
    a = len(text)
    for i in range(a,0,-1):
        print(text[i])

rev_string("Hello")
```

It shows the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rev_str.py", line 5, in <module>
    rev_string("Hello")
  File "rev_str.py", line 4, in rev_string
    print(text[i])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I also tried this code But the last character of the string couldn't be printed.

```
def rev_string(text):
    a = len(text)
    for i in range(a-1,0,-1):
        print(text[i])
rev_string("Hello")
```

Output:

```
python3 rev_str.py
o
l
l
e
```

Anyone, please help!

Comment: There is another way to do exactly what is asked for and not yet answered. This question is not an exact duplicate of #931092, strictly speaking. Here, @Vimal adds an extra `\n` after each character. So a complete and pythonic way can be something like: `print('\n'.join("Hello"[::-1]))` . There may be other answers there, so it might be closed too fast.

Comment: @kvorobiev: this may be a duplicate, but of an "off-by-one" mistake, not the currently linked "Reverse a string in Python"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an "off-by-one" error.  Look at your string manually, and then compare with the output of `range` manually.  Note, as you do this, that Python follows C's convention of 0-based indexes.  So:

```
>>> test = 'ABCDE'
>>> print('The first character is: -->{}<--'.format(test[0]))
The first character is: -->A<--
>>> a = len( test )
>>> [i for i in range(a, 0, -1)]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

Whoops!  Where's 0?  Hmm, well, let's try index 5:

```
>>> test[5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

So, as this feels like a homework problem, I'll not give an exact solution, but leave with "Given the above, how would you solve it?"

If this is not a homework question, consider [other methods of reversing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python) that have already been implemented ("Why reinvent the wheel?!")

Comment: Thats the answer I looking for!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use extended slice
https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices

```
str = 'hello world'
print(str[::-1])
>>>dlrow olleh
```

Comment: With out using the [::-1] any way thanks

Answer (score 0):

a = len(text) returns number of characters in text. For "Hello" a is equal to 5
and the characters in text are indexed from 0 to 4 like text[0] = 'H', text[1] = 'o', text[2] = 'l', text[3] = 'l' and text[4] = 'o'. So text[5] is invalid. Now  lets look at how range function generates number:

range(start, stop, step)

start: Starting number of the sequence.

stop: Generate numbers up to, but not including this number.

step: Difference between each number in the sequence.

range(4, 0, -1) generate number 4, 3, 2, 1

range(4, -1, -1) generate number 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

range(4, -2, -1) generate number 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1

So you range should be like:

```
rev_string(text):
    a = len(text)
    for i in range(a-1,-1,-1):
        print(text[i])
rev_string("Hello")
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works !!! And i have doubt what is means for **(a-1,-1,-1)** can you explain pls...>!

Comment: @VimalRaj edited

Comment: thanks man ! Help full again !☺

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it.

```
def rev_string(text):
    a = len(text)
    for i in range(1, a+1):
        print(text[a-i])
rev_string("Hello")
```

Output:

```
o
l
l
e
H
```

How it works:

`range(1, a+1)` produces `range(1,6)` `= [1,2,3,4,5`]

```
a = 5
```

Loop iterations:

```
iteration 1: i = 1, a-i = 5-1 = 4, text[4] = o 
iteration 2: i = 2, a-i = 5-2 = 3, text[3] = l 
iteration 3: i = 3, a-i = 5-3 = 2, text[2] = l 
iteration 4: i = 4, a-i = 5-4 = 1, text[1] = e 
iteration 5: i = 5, a-i = 5-5 = o, text[0] = H
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped me a lot !!! killing explanation.....

Comment: @VimalRaj if it helped, don't forget to mark it as answer or with a upvote :)

Comment: I also really want to do it but I don't have 15 reputation @utengr so so !

Comment: If I got that much i will do @utengr